# node node-tesseract-ocr in windows : Error: node:events ... write EOF

Tags: javascript, node.js, tesseract, node.js-fs

I run a node script on windows 11 and I am usig node-tesseract-ocr for reading text content  of a png file

```js
const tesseract = require("node-tesseract-ocr");
const fs = require("fs/promises");

async function main() {
  const img = await fs.readFile("buddy-screenshot.png");
  const text = await tesseract.recognize(img);

  console.log("Result:", text);
}

main();
```

It displays me an error :

```
    node:events:371
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: write EOF
    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (node:internal/stream_base_commons:98:16)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -4095,
  code: 'EOF',
  syscall: 'write'
}
```

Do you know what happens and how make it works?